# How to jump to the next tag in vim help file

Tags: vim

I want to learn the vim documentation given in the standard help file. But I am stuck on a navigating issue - I just cannot go to the next tag without having to position the cursor manually. I think you would agree that it is more productive to:

1. go to the next tag with some
   keystroke
2. press Ctrl-] to read corresponding
   topic
3. press Ctrl-o to return
4. continue reading initial text

PS. while I was writing this question, I tried some ideas on how to resolve this. I found that searching pipe character with `/|` is pretty close to what I want. But the tag is surrounded with two pipe '|' characters, so it's still not really optimized to use.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the `:tn` and `:tp` sequences to navigate between tags.

If you want to look for the next tag on the same help page, try this search:

```
/|.\{-}|
```

This means to search for:

- The character `|`
- Any characters up to the next `|`, matching as few as possible (that's what `\{-}` does).
- Another character `|`

This identifies the tags in the VIM help file.

Comment: This does not work. Mentioned combinations work only for tags searching. I'm talking about navigation without previous search

Comment: That's an extension of what I mentioned in the topic. I think I could map this to the <kbd>tab</kbd> and then it might work, thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you want to browse tags occasionally only, without mapping the search string to keyboard,

```
/|.*|
```

also does the trick, which is slightly easier to type in than the suggested

```
/|.\{-}|
```

For the case, that the "|" signs for the links in the help file are not visible, you can enable them with

```
:set conceallevel=0
```

To establish this setting permanently, please refer to [Defining the settings for the vim help file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957783/defining-the-settings-for-the-vim-help-file/25958054#25958054)

Answer (score 4):

Well, I don't really see the point. When I want to read everything, I simply use `<pagedown>` (or `<c-f>` with some terminals)

```
" .vim/ftplugin/help/navigate.vim
nnoremap <buffer> <tab> /\*\S\+\*/<cr>zt
```

?

Or do you mean:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <tab> /\|\zs\S\{-}\|/<cr><c-]>
```

?

Comment: yes, I meant the second.

But, speaking frankly, I was sure that vim has builtin command for this purpose and I just cannot find it.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply remap something like:

```
nmap ^\ /<Bar><Bslash>zs<Bslash>k<Bslash>+<Bar><CR>
```

where ^\ is entered as (on my keyboard) Ctrl-V Ctrl-#: choose whatever shortcut you want.

This does a single key search for a `|` followed by one or more keyword characters and then a `|`.  It puts the cursor on the first keyword character.  The  and  bits are there due to the way map works, see

```
:help :map-special-chars
```

As an aside, I imagine that ctrl-t would make more sense than ctrl-o as it's a more direct opposite of ctrl-], but it's up to you.  Having said that, ctrl-o will allow you to go back to before the search as well.

Comment: No need for <Bar> and <Bslash> here. | and \ are more than enough in this context.

Comment: @Luc - I tried that initially, but got `E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &`.  Replacing the `|` and `\` with `<Bar>` and `<Bslash>` cured it.

Comment: My mistake. It needs to be `\|`